# Use DbContext in repository

Tags: c#, repository, dbcontext, unit-of-work

I used repository and UnitOfWork Design pattern in my project.I have some common CRUD function in generic repository that all repository inherit that.In act I have one repository per entity
in project.So my question is can I access directly DbContext from Repository or not?
I want to create Projection model from two entity but in different repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can do that - you can provide protected DbContext from base repository. But I don't think that accessing other repositories from repository is a very good idea. It's better to place such operation (which uses several repositories) into domain service.